# NSTableView / NSOutlineView reload specified rows

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I'm implementing drag & drop / reordering in an `NSOutlineView`.

My data is like this:

```
Root
   Child1
   Child2
   Child3
```

The user will be able to reorder the children by drag & drop.

If I use `reloadData(forRowIndexes:columnIndexes:)` in the method handling the Drop, 
the `NSOutlineView` doesn't update, while a simple `reloadData()` works fine.

I wanted my app to be as efficient as possible, so how to use this `reloadData(forRowIndexes:columnIndexes:)`?

The related code is here:

```
info.enumerateDraggingItems(
        options: .clearNonenumeratedImages,
        for: self.outlineView,
        classes: classes,
        searchOptions: [:])
    { [unowned self] (
        draggingItem: NSDraggingItem,
        idx,
        stop) -> Void in
        let dragged = self.currentlyDraggedObjects![idx] as! RowItem
        let oldParent = dragged.parent!
        let siblings = oldParent.children

        let oldIndex = siblings?.index(where: { (item) -> Bool in
            item.identifier == dragged.identifier
        })

        oldParent.moveChild(from: oldIndex!, to: insertionPos)

        let parentRow = self.outlineView.row(forItem: item)

        let reloadRowRange = oldIndex! < insertionPos ?
            (oldIndex! + parentRow + 1)...(insertionPos + parentRow + 1)
            : (insertionPos + parentRow + 1)...(oldIndex! + parentRow + 1)

        #if DEBUG
            print(#file, #line, reloadRowRange)
        #endif

        // self.outlineView.reloadData() // This works!

        // Doesn't work, why?
        self.outlineView.reloadData(
            forRowIndexes: IndexSet(reloadRowRange),
            columnIndexes: IndexSet(integer: 0)
        )
    }
```

Comment: Don't reload, move (or remove and insert) the rows.

Comment: Thanks! The animation for move seems too much. So I ended up using remove and insert.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Willeke's comment, now the rows are updated correctly, by:

```
self.outlineView.removeItems(at: IndexSet(integer: oldIndex!),
                                          inParent: oldParent)
self.outlineView.insertItems(at: IndexSet(integer: newIndex),
                                          inParent: oldParent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding and removing an item seems fine.

```
let row = 0
outlineView.removeItems(at: IndexSet(integer: row), inParent: nil, withAnimation: .effectFade)
outlineView.insertItems(at: IndexSet(integer: row), inParent: nil, withAnimation: .effectFade)
```